# How to add a new step in progress bar

Tags: angular

I have a stepper in my form and it has 3 steps (1.emp-details, 2.emp-address, 3.emp-contact 4.verify). Now we are going to add one more step in the middle like (1.emp-details, 2.emp-address, 3. emp-employment-history 4.emp-contact 5.verify).The 4th step should be visible based on the state. If it is in employee state i should display 5 steps. Else only 4 steps should be displayed. I can take the state details. But no idea how to add one more step in the middle and don't know how to achieve that.Can anyone suggest how to add one more step in the middle based on the condition.

My existing code is,

```
stepper(){
const item1 = new Item(",");
item1.name = "Emp details";

const item2 = new Item(",");
item2.name = "Emp address";

const item3 = new Item(",");
item3.name = "Emp contact";

this. stepper = new Stepper(
1,
0,
[item1, item2, item3, item4],
false
);
}
```

Comment: Can you also include the template code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass the items as an array to the stepper constructor, you could create an array to hold al the steps and only push the third step if it is in employee state

```
stepper(){
   const items = [];

   const item1 = new Item(",");
   item1.name = "Emp details";
   items.push(item1);

   const item2 = new Item(",");
   item2.name = "Emp address";
   items.push(item2);

   if (isInEmployeeState()) { // check for the state here
      const item3 = new Item(",");
      item3.name = "emp-employment-history";
      items.push(item3);
   }

   const item4 = new Item(",");
   item4.name = "Emp contact";
   items.push(item4);

   this.stepper = new Stepper(1, 0, items, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function that is a JS built-in function.

Syntax:

```
arr.splice(0, 0, item);

// array.splice(index: number, deleteCount: number, newItem: any)
```

In this example you are adding `item` to index `0` with `0` deletion.

In your case you can use something like:

```
items.splice(4, 0, item4);
```